# How to override __unicode__ method for User model in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to do this in Django 1.5?

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

and I'd like to override it so its:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

Comment: And that doesn't work? What problems did you encounter when you tried this?

Comment: Are you defining your own [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just don't know how to add this code to make it work


I don't define the custom user model. I just want to override  this one method.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use a proxy model.

```
class CustomUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

Then set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to that one in your `settings.py` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for info)